# Determining a SQL Server Identity Column Name in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write some generic code in VB.NET that determines whether or not a SQL server database table contains an identity column and, if so, to return the name of that column.

I'm working in Visual Basic 2008 Express and have created a SQL database, "MyDatabase" with 1 table called "MyTable".  Within that table, I've got 3 columns, "ID", "Column1" and "Column2".  I know, I know... inventive names.  Under column properties in the Database Explorer, I've set the "ID" column "Identity Specification" to "yes" and have set the "Is Identity" value to "yes".

I need for the .NET code to return "ID" as the identity column.  Can this be done through LINQ or some other means?

Thanks very much in advance!

Luck

Answer (score 3):

Use SQLDataReader to open MyTable (SELECT ID from myTable WHERE 1 = 2) & use GetSchemaTable method, which will give you the datatable.

As per the docs, check for the content of a column named IsAutoIncrement. If it returns true, it should be an Identity column.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx

Note: This is purely based on my memory & help from the MSDN docs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Linq to SQL DataContext, you can obtain table metadata by querying the data context [MappingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.mappingsource.aspx):

```
var ctx = new YourDataContext();
var identityAndKey = ctx.Mapping.MappingSource
                                .GetModel(typeof(YourDataContext)) 
                                .GetMetaType(typeof(YourTable))
                                .DataMembers
                                .SingleOrDefault(i => i.IsDbGenerated &&
                                                      i.IsPrimaryKey);
```

You will get a [MetaDataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metadatamember.aspx) instance, which is the Primary Key and DbGenerated (Identity) property of your data class. The column name is available on the `Name` property.

With a little bit of reflection, you could be able to re-utilize this code for any table/data context.

Answer (score 0):

You could call sp_columns stored procedure to obtain this informatión and more:

```
SqlConnection sqlConx = new SqlConnection(p_conectionStrWithDB);
sqlConx.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_columns", sqlConx);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@table_name", TableName));
DataTable tblColumns = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(tblColumns);
```

Edit: You can also obtain information about primary Keys like this:

```
SqlConnection sqlConx = new SqlConnection(p_conectionStrWithDB);
sqlConx.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pkeys", sqlConx);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@table_name", tableName));
DataTable tblConstraints = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(tblConstraints);
return tblConstraints;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers.

Jonathan - I've run your code and can see a lot of column information including DATA_TYPE, RADIX, NULLABLE, SQL_DATA_TYPE and SS_DATA_TYPE but I still don't see any information on the primary key.

Please forgive this question which must seem incredibly simple.  I've only just started to work with SQL.

Thanks again,
Luck

Comment: This code let you know what column is Identity, you can read the "TYPE_NAME" column of the datatable. If the column type is INT and is identity the column will contain "int Identity". I Will Edit my answer to add code about obtain Primary Key Info.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This is exactly what I needed.

Cheers,
Luck